# NSString and UITapGestureRecognizer as method arguments

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am wondering how to use a `NSString` and a `UITapGestureRecoginzer` as method arguments in Xcode.
Now I have this code:

```
-(void)setLanguage:(NSString *)language :(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    gesture.view.alpha = 0.8;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:language forKey:@"GameLanguage"];
}
```

and this for the`UITapGestureRecognizer`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(setLanguage:@"en":tap)];
    [ENImage addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

When I try it this way I only get errors. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action of `UITapGestureRecognizer`'s  can only take one parameter, which is itself or no parameter. Please review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034956/custom-actions-for-uigesturerecognizers-with-custom-parameters).
I find your "language" is a constant `NSString` "en", why not try this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
[ENImage addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

In your `-tapped:`

```
- (void)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    gesture.view.alpha = 0.8;
    // Or you can call your custom method like [self setLanguage:@"en"]
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"en" forKey:@"GameLanguage"];
}
```

Comment: So I cannot use one method for multiple `UITapGestureRecognizer`'s?

Comment: This is [the document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html):"A gesture recognizer has one or more target-action pairs associated with it. If there are multiple target-action pairs, they are discrete, and not cumulative. Recognition of a gesture results in the dispatch of an action message to a target for each of those pairs. The action methods invoked must conform to one of the following signatures:"
    `- (void)handleGesture;`
    `- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the name of the second parameter
`-(void) setLanguage:(NSString *)language withGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture` is the correct signature

Comment: And how do I call this in the action selector?

Comment: You could just create a simple convenience selector like `@selector(imageTapped:)` with signature `-(void)imageTapped:(id)sender` and there you can call your custom selector

Comment: Can you put that in the code of mine? So I can understand how to do that.

Comment: `-(void)imageTapped:(id)sender {
[self setLanguage:@"en" withGesture:sender];
}`

something like this should work

Comment: `UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
    [ENImage addGestureRecognizer:tap];`

Comment: But I want to have the language string as a argument

Comment: I'm pretty confident that the `@selector` keyword doesn't let you specify default arguments. That's why you should use custom methods like `imageTapped:` to do that

Answer (score 0):

try this:

replace your gesture allocation coding with following lines

```
NSString *strLanguage = @"en";
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(setLanguage:strLanguage:)];
[ENImage addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

and replace your setLanguage method with following code

```
-(void)setLanguage : (NSString *) language : (id)sender {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;
    gesture.view.alpha = 0.8;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:language forKey:@"GameLanguage"];
}
```

Comment: But I would like to have 2 arguments

Comment: When I use 1 argument it works, but when I try to use 2, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(setLanguage:@"en":tap)]
```

When using the `@selector()` syntax, you cannot pass parameters. `@selector` is a macro that will search across table at runtime for a method matching the given signature, so passing argument within the parentheses is not such a good idea :-)
 You should use

```
@selector(setLanguage::)
```

Then, becuase that is how `UIGesture Recognizers` are made, the method you provide as action MUST accept 0 or 1 parameter, not more! And if your method accept 1 parameter, AUTOMATICLY it will be the triggered gesture recognizer that will be passed.

So, in your situation, like liuyaodong adviced, change your tapHandling method to  something like

```
- (void)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
```

and in this method's body, you'll have to figure out the language.

Cheers,