# Add selector with arguments to an action

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm trying to associate a selector to a UILongPressGestureRecognizer action and that selector corresponds to a function that receives one argument.

So my question is, how can i set the UILongPressGestureRecognizer action to the selector and pass it the argument ?

My function (selector) is:

```
-(void)MyFunction:(NSInteger)paramether
 {
     //some code
 }
```

And i set it on the UILongPressGestureRecognizer here:

```
longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(MyFunction)];
```

If MyFunction has any paramether it will works fine but if i set it to receive some paramether it will not work

Comment: To avoid the `unrecognized selector` error, replace `@selector(MyFunction)` by: `@selector(MyFunction:)`.

Comment: The problem is not exactly that.
But how to pass a specific value to MyFunction

Comment: For example, i want to do something like @selector(MyFunction:4) 
And 4 is the argument to MyFunction

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034956/custom-actions-for-uigesturerecognizers-with-custom-parameters/5035335#5035335

Comment: You can't do this. Why don't you update your question to explain what you're trying to accomplish in more detail, so we can suggest another way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add use arguments for target-action registration (excepting (id)sender). But you can use methods from `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`. Also you can retrieve some useful information from (id)sender.